# More than 2 conditions in FilterExpression

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The scan works fine if I provide two or less filter conditions, like this:

```js
FilterExpression: '#locationID = :areaID and #price >= :minPrice'
```

But if I add a third condition, I get no results:

```js
FilterExpression: '#locationID = :areaID and #price >= :minPrice and #offeringType = :offeringType'
```

I tried using only `#offeringType`, the condition is working properly by itself.
Can I have more than two conditions?

Full code:

```js
let params = {
  TableName: 'properties',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#locationID': 'locationID',
      '#price': 'price',
      '#offeringType': 'offeringType',
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':areaID': areaID,
      ':minPrice': parseInt(minPrice),
      ':offeringType': offeringType
  },
  FilterExpression: '#locationID = :areaID and #price >= :minPrice and #offeringType = :offeringType'
}

documentClient.scan(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      reject()
  } else {
      resolve(data)
  }
})
```

Thanks

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but do you in fact have items in your table matching all 3 conditions?

Comment: @404 Yes I do, double checked

Answer (score 0):

The expression was acting weird because `#price` wasn't a Number in the database. Chaining expressions with AND works fine.